# Mystery null reference

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System

Public Class Form1

    Private Class movie
        Public name As String
        Public actors() As String
        Public year As String
        Public country As String
        Public votes As String

    End Class

    Private movies(0) As movie
    Private fs As FileStream
    Private input As StreamReader

    Private Sub LoadToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadToolStripMenuItem.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Dim currentmv As New movie
        Dim reader As String()


        If File.Exists(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) Then

            lblPath.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim iFile As New StreamReader(lblPath.Text)

            While Not iFile.EndOfStream

                reader = iFile.ReadLine.Split(";")

                currentmv.name = reader(0)
                currentmv.actors = reader(1).Split(",")
                currentmv.year = reader(2)
                currentmv.country = reader(3)
                currentmv.votes = reader(4)

                lbMovies.Items.Add(currentmv.name)

                movies(i) = currentmv

                i = i + 1
                ReDim movies(i)

            End While
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub lbMovies_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbMovies.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim i As Integer

        For i = 0 To movies(lbMovies.SelectedIndex).actors.Length

            lbActors.Items.Add(movies(lbMovies.SelectedIndex).actors(i))

        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Problem strikes when I request the length.  It says it's a null reference, but I cannot see any mistake in this.  Is there an issue when I request the length of the array in an array of objects?

Comment: Has the file actually been loaded at the point where you get the exception? What happened when you tried debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ReDim Preserve movies(i)
```

IIRC `ReDim` will initialize all elements to `Nothing` without `Preserve`.

Comment: ReDim is convenient but wasteful since is creates a brand new Array everytime it's used, even with Preserve (see http://www.aspheute.com/english/20001025.asp ). As igrimpe says, using List(Of ...) is the preferred way to go for when your list of items may grow or shrink many times over. ReDim is otherwise okay if executed sparingly (such as to create a buffer that gets reused many times over); and with Preserve if the Array size is small (under 100 elements).

Answer (score 1):

Using an Array to store your data AND storing their "names" in a Listbox isn't necessary. The Listbox doesn't store `String`, but `Object`. You can store your data INSIDE the Listbox itself.

```
Private Class Data
    Public SomeNumber As Integer
    Public SomeString As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", SomeString, SomeNumber)
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ListBox1.Items.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "John", .SomeNumber = 12})
    ListBox1.Items.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "Paul", .SomeNumber = 36})
    ListBox1.Items.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "Ringo", .SomeNumber = 48})

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim d As Data = DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedItem
    If d IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

**OR** you store your data in a list and `bind` it to your listbox:

```
Private Class Data
    Public SomeNumber As Integer
    Public SomeString As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", SomeString, SomeNumber)
    End Function
End Class

Private datalist As New List(Of Data)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    datalist.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "John", .SomeNumber = 12})
    datalist.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "Paul", .SomeNumber = 36})
    datalist.Add(New Data With {.SomeString = "Ringo", .SomeNumber = 48})

    ListBox1.DataSource = datalist

End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim d As Data = DirectCast(sender, ListBox).SelectedItem
    If d IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 because List(Of ...) is indeed what I use myself, a superior way to go over ReDim Preserve.